# Problems when using the tabview and collection view of the devexpress maui component together

Tags: devexpress, maui

I'm having trouble using my devexpress maui component
My devexpress version is using version 23.1.6
Below my content page, there is a tab view that displays several product categories.

```
...
<dxc:TabView x:Name="tvMain"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ProductModelsByCategory}"
            SelectedItemIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
            HeaderPanelBackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BasePageColor}"
            HeaderPanelItemSpacing="10"
            HeaderPanelMinHeight="20"
            HeaderPanelIndent="0"
            SelectedItemIndicatorHeight="3"
            SelectedItemIndicatorColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"
            ItemHeaderMinWidth="50"
            HeaderPanelShadowColor="{DynamicResource AreaBorder}"
            IsHeaderPanelShadowVisible="True"
            HeaderPanelShadowRadius="7"
            HeaderPanelShadowHeight="7">
    <dxc:TabView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Label Text="{Binding CategoryName}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource isSelectedToColorConverter}}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxc:TabView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
    <dxc:TabView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxc:TabView.ItemTemplate>
</dxc:TabView>
...
```

And the content of each tab uses DXCollectionView to display the product list.

```
...
<dxcv:DXCollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ProductModels}"
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
        IsLoadMoreEnabled="True"
        LoadMoreCommand="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}"
        PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding PullToRefreshCommand}"
        IndicatorColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"
        IsScrollBarVisible="False">
    <dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="100,*,Auto">
                    <Image
                        Aspect="AspectFit"
                        HeightRequest="60"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        Source="https://mblogthumb-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTAxMDhfMTU0/MDAxNTQ2OTMxNTE1MjIx.W2PR2ar26ENq4Gd9S61Rn0l396tFwkpHnn1DUm4t0BMg.QVfzmrwqNc32QRScIZR_w4DoG4sPsL6raze_tR9waJ8g.JPEG.bruceppt/0003.JPG?type=w800"/>
                    <!--Source="{Binding ProductImage}"-->
                    <StackLayout
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="8"
                        Spacing="2"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                        <Label
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Style="{StaticResource Subhead}"
                            Text="{Binding CategoryName}"
                            VerticalOptions="Start" />

                        <Label
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Style="{StaticResource Title2}"
                            Text="{Binding ProductName}"
                            VerticalOptions="Start" />

                        <Label
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Style="{StaticResource Subhead}"
                            Text="{Binding CategoryName}"
                            VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="5">
                            <Label
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                Style="{StaticResource Title1}"
                                Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
                                TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray100}"
                                VerticalOptions="Start" />
                            <Label
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                Style="{StaticResource Title1}"
                                Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
                                TextColor="{DynamicResource Red}"
                                VerticalOptions="Start" />
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Margin="8,8,8,8"
                        Spacing="10"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <!--  QUANTITY  -->

                        <!--  REMOVE BUTTON  -->
                        <Border
                            Padding="0"
                            Background="{DynamicResource Red}"
                            HeightRequest="30"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15,15,15,15"
                            StrokeThickness="0"
                            WidthRequest="30">

                            <Label
                                FontFamily="MaterialDesign"
                                FontSize="20"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Text="{x:Static views:MaterialDesignIcons.Add}"
                                TextColor="{DynamicResource White}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" >
                                </Label>
                        </Border>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
                <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource AreaBorder}" HeightRequest="1" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</dxcv:DXCollectionView>
...
```

The problem here is that when the product list of each tab view is displayed, if you make a touch gesture to the right or left, the tab view switches, and sometimes it does not work.

Is there any way to improve it?

The full source is below:

```
 <dxc:TabView x:Name="tvMain"
             Grid.Row="1"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ProductModelsByCategory}"
             SelectedItemIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
             HeaderPanelBackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BasePageColor}"
             HeaderPanelItemSpacing="10"
             HeaderPanelMinHeight="20"
             HeaderPanelIndent="0"
             SelectedItemIndicatorHeight="3"
             SelectedItemIndicatorColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"
             ItemHeaderMinWidth="50"
             HeaderPanelShadowColor="{DynamicResource AreaBorder}"
             IsHeaderPanelShadowVisible="True"
             HeaderPanelShadowRadius="7"
             HeaderPanelShadowHeight="7">
     <dxc:TabView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
                 <Label Text="{Binding CategoryName}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource isSelectedToColorConverter}}"/>
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
     </dxc:TabView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
     <dxc:TabView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <dxcv:DXCollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding ProductModels}"
                     IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                     IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                     IsLoadMoreEnabled="True"
                     LoadMoreCommand="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}"
                     PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding PullToRefreshCommand}"
                     IndicatorColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"
                     IsScrollBarVisible="False">
                 <dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <VerticalStackLayout>
                             <Grid ColumnDefinitions="100,*,Auto">
                                 <Image
                                     Aspect="AspectFit"
                                     HeightRequest="60"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                                     Source="https://mblogthumb-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTAxMDhfMTU0/MDAxNTQ2OTMxNTE1MjIx.W2PR2ar26ENq4Gd9S61Rn0l396tFwkpHnn1DUm4t0BMg.QVfzmrwqNc32QRScIZR_w4DoG4sPsL6raze_tR9waJ8g.JPEG.bruceppt/0003.JPG?type=w800"/>
                                 <!--Source="{Binding ProductImage}"-->
                                 <StackLayout
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     Margin="8"
                                     Spacing="2"
                                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                                     <Label
                                         HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                         Style="{StaticResource Subhead}"
                                         Text="{Binding CategoryName}"
                                         VerticalOptions="Start" />

                                     <Label
                                         HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                         Style="{StaticResource Title2}"
                                         Text="{Binding ProductName}"
                                         VerticalOptions="Start" />

                                     <Label
                                         HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                         Style="{StaticResource Subhead}"
                                         Text="{Binding CategoryName}"
                                         VerticalOptions="Start" />
                                     <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="5">
                                         <Label
                                             HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                             Style="{StaticResource Title1}"
                                             Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
                                             TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray100}"
                                             VerticalOptions="Start" />
                                         <Label
                                             HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                             Style="{StaticResource Title1}"
                                             Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
                                             TextColor="{DynamicResource Red}"
                                             VerticalOptions="Start" />
                                     </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                 </StackLayout>

                                 <StackLayout
                                     Grid.Column="2"
                                     Margin="8,8,8,8"
                                     Spacing="10"
                                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                     <!--  QUANTITY  -->

                                     <!--  REMOVE BUTTON  -->
                                     <Border
                                         Padding="0"
                                         Background="{DynamicResource Red}"
                                         HeightRequest="30"
                                         HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                         StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15,15,15,15"
                                         StrokeThickness="0"
                                         WidthRequest="30">

                                         <Label
                                             FontFamily="MaterialDesign"
                                             FontSize="20"
                                             HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                             Text="{x:Static views:MaterialDesignIcons.Add}"
                                             TextColor="{DynamicResource White}"
                                             VerticalOptions="Center" >
                                             </Label>
                                     </Border>
                                 </StackLayout>
                             </Grid>
                             <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource AreaBorder}" HeightRequest="1" />
                         </VerticalStackLayout>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
             </dxcv:DXCollectionView>
         </DataTemplate>
     </dxc:TabView.ItemTemplate>
 </dxc:TabView>
```

Comment: Try setting SwipeEnabled to false